# How adding a table with js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want add a table on my html table via JavaScript.

I've already tried using the `appendChild` and `insertBefore` methods, but those didn't work.

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var utilisateur = [{
    id: 51,
    checked: false,
    prenom: "Dolores",
    date: "Fermière",
    examen: "host",
    note: "ww.dolores@gmail.com"
  }, {
    id: 52,
    checked: true,
    prenom: "Bernard",
    date: "Robopsycologue",
    examen: "human",
    note: "ww.bernard@gmail.com"
  }
  // {
  //   id: 3,
  //   name: "Robert",
  //   job: "Directeur",
  //   specie: "human",
  //   email: "ww.robert@gmail.com"
  // },
  // {
  //   id: 4,
  //   name: "Maeve",
  //   job: "Maquerelle",
  //   specie: "host",
  //   email: "ww.maeve@gmail.com"
  // },
  // {
  //   id: 5,
  //   name: "Teddy",
  //   job: "Inconnu",
  //   specie: "host",
  //   email: "ww.teddy@gmail.com"
  // },
  // {
  //   id: 6,
  //   name: "William",
  //   job: "Actionnaire",
  //   specie: "human",
  //   email: "ww.william@gmail.com"
  // },
  // {
  //   id: 7,
  //   name: "Elsie",
  //   job: "Programmeuse",
  //   specie: "human",
  //   email: "ww.elsie@gmail.com"
  // },
  // {
  //  id: 8,
  //  name: "Nathanael",
  //  job: "Dev",
  //  specie: "human",
  //  email: "s.nathanael@outlook.fr" 
  // }
];
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  var cell0 = document.createElement("td");
  var cell1 = document.createElement("td");
  var atr = document.createAttribute("class");
  atr.value = "bs-checkbox";
  cell1.setAttributeNode(atr);
  var para = document.createElement("input");
  var para1 = document.createAttribute("data-index");
  var para2 = document.createAttribute("name");
  var para3 = document.createAttribute("type");
  para1.value = "0";
  para2.value = "btSelectItem";
  para3.value = "checkbox";
  para.setAttributeNode(para1);
  para.setAttributeNode(para2);
  para.setAttributeNode(para3)
  cell1.appendChild(para);
  // var cell1 = '<td class="bs-checkbox"></td>'
  //alert(cell1).innerText;
  var cell2 = document.createElement("td");
  var cell3 = document.createElement("td");
  var cell4 = document.createElement("td");
  var cell5 = document.createElement("td");
  var cell6 = document.createElement("td");
  var cell7 = document.createElement("td");
  var cell8 = document.createElement("td");
  cell0.innerText = utilisateur[i].id;
  cell1.innerText = utilisateur[i].checked
  cell2.innerText = utilisateur[i].prenom;
  cell3.innerText = utilisateur[i].date;
  cell4.innerText = utilisateur[i].examen;
  cell5.innerText = utilisateur[i].note;
  row.appendChild(cell0);
  row.appendChild(cell1);
  row.appendChild(cell2);
  row.appendChild(cell3);
  row.appendChild(cell4);
  row.appendChild(cell5);
  // row.appendChild(cell6);
  // row.appendChild(cell7);
  // row.appendChild(cell8);
  // document.getElementsById("tbody")[0].appendChild(row);
  // var elem = document.getElementsById("tabs1");
  // var mychild = document.getElementById("")
  // elem.insertBefore(mypara, mychild);
  // elem.appendChild(row);
  var element = document.getElementById("tabs1")[0];
  element.appendChild(row);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(cell1).toggleClass("bs-checkbox");
});
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="tabs" id="tabs1">
  <!-- <table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th class="col">Name</th>
        <th class="col">Job</th>
        <th class="col">Attribut</th>
        <th class="col">Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table> -->
</div>
<table class="table" data-click-to-select="true" data-filter-control="true" data-search="true" data-show-export="true" data-toggle="table" data-toolbar="#toolbar" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="0" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;"></th>
      <th data-checkbox="true" data-field="state"></th>
      <th data-field="prenom" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">Prénom</th>
      <th data-field="date" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Date</th>
      <th data-field="examen" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Examen</th>
      <th data-field="note" data-sortable="true">Note</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr>
      <td id="1" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;"></td>
      <td class="bs-checkbox"><input data-index="0" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox"></td>
      <td>Valérie</td>
      <td>01/09/2015</td>
      <td>Français</td>
      <td>12/20</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want add my table JavaScript on my `div` on `tbody`, but he always go after my `tbody`.

The problem is, even if i create another `div` for my JavaScript, he never go on this `div`, so i want put my JavaScript on my `div` tabs1.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a `<div>` inside a table body, so it is placed outside it, and so are your inserts. If you change this code:

```
var element = document.getElementById("tabs1")[0];
element.appendChild(row);
```

to this:

```
var element = document.getElementById("tbody");
element.appendChild(row);
```

it seems to work, somewhat. See: https://jsfiddle.net/KIKO_Software/kqr48uxj/4/

New rows are now added to the table body.

Answer (score 0):

A number of issues...

You can't have a `<div>` as the child of a `<tbody>` because that is invalid HTML... so I would suggest you remove the `<div>` (also remember you **can** have multiple `<tbody>` tags within a `<table>` meaning you can split them up into section with separate `id` attributes, etc).

The function call of `document.getElementById("tabs1")` will return a single object, not an array - so you don't need the `[0]` at the end...

```
var element = document.getElementById("tabs1");
```

And lastly, you're going from 0 to 99 in your `for` loop, but the data you've provided only goes from 0 to 1 (or 0 to 7 with the commented out data)... however, you're trying to access `utilisateur[i]` and if the value of `i` is more than the number of items of data in the array, you will get an error in your developer console.  So you need to check that there are enough items in `utilisateur.length`...

```
if (i < utilisateur.length) {
  cell0.innerText = utilisateur[i].id;
  cell1.innerText = utilisateur[i].checked
  ...
}
```

```js
var utilisateur = [
  {
    id: 51,
    checked: false,
    prenom: "Dolores",
    date: "Fermière",
    examen: "host",
    note: "ww.dolores@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    id: 52,
    checked: true,
    prenom: "Bernard",
    date: "Robopsycologue",
    examen: "human",
    note: "ww.bernard@gmail.com"
  }
];

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  var cell0 = document.createElement("td");
  var cell1 = document.createElement("td");

  var atr = document.createAttribute("class");
  atr.value = "bs-checkbox";
  cell1.setAttributeNode(atr);
  var para = document.createElement("input");
  var para1 = document.createAttribute("data-index");
  var para2 = document.createAttribute("name");
  var para3 = document.createAttribute("type");
  para1.value = "0";
  para2.value = "btSelectItem";
  para3.value = "checkbox";
  para.setAttributeNode(para1);
  para.setAttributeNode(para2);
  para.setAttributeNode(para3)
  cell1.appendChild(para);



  // var cell1 = '<td class="bs-checkbox"></td>'
  //alert(cell1).innerText;
  var cell2 = document.createElement("td");
  var cell3 = document.createElement("td");
  var cell4 = document.createElement("td");
  var cell5 = document.createElement("td");
  var cell6 = document.createElement("td");
  var cell7 = document.createElement("td");
  var cell8 = document.createElement("td");
  if (i < utilisateur.length) {
    cell0.innerText = utilisateur[i].id;
    cell1.innerText = utilisateur[i].checked
    cell2.innerText = utilisateur[i].prenom;   
    cell3.innerText = utilisateur[i].date;
    cell4.innerText = utilisateur[i].examen;
    cell5.innerText = utilisateur[i].note;
  }
  row.appendChild(cell0);
  row.appendChild(cell1);
  row.appendChild(cell2);
  row.appendChild(cell3);
  row.appendChild(cell4);
  row.appendChild(cell5);
  // row.appendChild(cell6);
  // row.appendChild(cell7);
  // row.appendChild(cell8);

  // document.getElementsById("tbody")[0].appendChild(row);

  // var elem = document.getElementsById("tabs1");
  // var mychild = document.getElementById("")
  // elem.insertBefore(mypara, mychild);
  // elem.appendChild(row);
  var element = document.getElementById("tbody");
  element.appendChild(row);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(cell1).toggleClass("bs-checkbox");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" class="table"
            data-toggle="table"
            data-search="true"
            data-filter-control="true" 
            data-show-export="true"
            data-click-to-select="true"
            data-toolbar="#toolbar">
  <thead>
     <tr>
        <th id="0" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;"></th>
        <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
        <th data-field="prenom" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">Prénom</th>
        <th data-field="date" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Date</th>
        <th data-field="examen" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Examen</th>
        <th data-field="note" data-sortable="true">Note</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbody">
     <tr>
        <td id="1" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;"></td>
        <td class="bs-checkbox ">      <input data-index="0" name="btSelectItem" type="checkbox">      </td>
        <td>Valérie</td>
        <td>01/09/2015</td>
        <td>Français</td>
        <td>12/20</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple solution, using ES6 string interpolation

For example we have an array of objects

```
employees: [
 {
    name: 'John Doe',
    phone: '00000000',
 },
 {
   name: 'George Daniels',
   phone: '11111111',
 }
]
```

and a table html object.

you can append rows like this:

```
for (let employee of employees) {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    row.innerHTML = `<td>${employee.name}</td>
                     <td>${employee.phone}</td>`;
    table.appendChild(row);
   }
```