# Table didn't recognize my data from javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want put my data with JS on my table, with a search bar

I already try to put my data on table or my tbody but that didn't work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>A Pen by  Augusto</title>
      <link rel='stylesheet' href="jquery-ui.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
      <title>CodePen - A Pen by  Augusto</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Table Sorter Final</h1>
      <input type="search" class="light-table-filter" data-table="search-table" placeholder="Search..">
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <div id="combito">
         <div id="separator"></div>
         <div class="opt-combito" id="asc">
            <!-- <img src="images/hmenu-asc.gif" alt="" /> --> <!-- non utiliser -->
            <span>Sort Ascending</span>
         </div>
         <div class="opt-combito" id="desc">
            <!-- <img src="images/hmenu-desc.gif" alt="" /> --> <!-- non utiliser -->
            <span>Sort Descending</span>
         </div>
      </div>
      <table class="filter-table" style="border-spacing: 0px;">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th style="padding: 0px;"><input type="text" style="display:block;width: 95%;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;" class="searchByColumn" /></th>
               <th style="padding: 0px;"><input type="text" style="display:block;width: 95%;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;" class="searchByColumn" /></th>
               <th style="padding: 0px;">
                  <div style="width:95%">&nbsp;</div>
               </th>
               <th style="padding: 0px;"><input type="text" style="display:block;width: 95%;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;" class="searchByColumn" /></th>
               <th style="padding: 0px;">
                  <select   style="display:block;width: 95%;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;" class="searchByColumn">
                     <option selected="true" value="">--All--</option>
                  </select>
               </th>
               <th style="padding: 0px;">
                  <select  style="display:block;width: 95%;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;" class="searchByColumn">
                     <option  selected="true" value="">--All--</option>
                  </select>
               </th>
               <th style="padding: 0px;">
                  <select  style="display:block;width: 95%;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;" class="searchByColumn">
                     <option  selected="true" value="">--All--</option>
                  </select>
               </th>
               <th style="padding: 0px;">
                  <select style="display:block;width:95%;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;" class="searchByColumn">
                     <option  selected="true" value="">--All--</option>
                  </select>
               </th>
               <th style="padding: 0px;">
                  <select style="display:block;width: 95%;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;" class="searchByColumn">
                     <option  selected="true" value="">--All--</option>
                  </select>
               </th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
      </table>
      <table id="table" class="sortable search-table">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th id="column-a" class="menu">ID</th>
               <th data-field="Name" data-checkbox="true" class="menu">Name</th>
               <th data-field="Phone" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true" class="menu">Phone</th>
               <th data-field="Email" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true" class="menu">Email</th>
               <th data-field="City" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true" class="menu">City</th>
               <th data-field="State" data-sortable="true" class="menu">State</th>
               <th data-field="Zipcode" data-sortable="true" class="menu">Zip Code</th>
               <th data-field="Status" data-sortable="true" class="menu">Status</th>
               <th data-field="Vehicle" data-sortable="true" class="menu">Vehicle</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody id="tbody">
            <div id="tabs1" class="tabs">
            </div>
         </tbody>
      </table>
      <script src='https://codepen.io/assets/libs/fullpage/jquery_and_jqueryui.js'></script> <!-- non utiliser -->
      <script src="js/index.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
      <script src="./script.js"></script>
      <script src="tableau.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

My javascript file:

```
 var utilisateur = [                                       // donnée du tableau
        {
        id = '1',
        Name ='Kaseem Huber',
        Phone ='(587) 117-5521',
        Email = '.@samecore.org',
        City = 'Burlington',
        State = 'DE',
        ZipCode = '81070',
        Status = 'Aproved',
        Vehicle = 'Toyota'
        },
        {
        id = '2',
        Name ='Oleg Michael',
        Phone ='(539) 184-8550',
        Email = 'pages@andit.edu',
        City = 'Covina',
        State = 'SC',
        ZipCode = '48758',
        Status = 'Aproved',
        Vehicle = 'Toyota'
        }
      ];

      for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        var row = document.createElement("tr");                   // créer le tableau

        var cell0 = document.createElement("td");
        var cell1 = document.createElement("td");
        var cell2 = document.createElement("td");
        var cell3 = document.createElement("td");
        var cell4 = document.createElement("td");
        var cell5 = document.createElement("td");
        var cell6 = document.createElement("td");
        var cell7 = document.createElement("td");
        var cell8 = document.createElement("td");
        cell0.innerText = utilisateur[i].id;
        cell1.innerText = utilisateur[i].Name;
        cell2.innerText = utilisateur[i].Phone;   
        cell3.innerText = utilisateur[i].Email;
        cell4.innerText = utilisateur[i].City;
        cell5.innerText = utilisateur[i].State;
        cell6.innerText = utilisateur[i].ZipCode;
        cell7.innerText = utilisateur[i].Status;
        cell8.innerText = utilisateur[i].Vehicle;
        row.appendChild(cell0);                                    // afficher dans le tableau la cellule 
        row.appendChild(cell1);
        row.appendChild(cell2);
        row.appendChild(cell3);
        row.appendChild(cell4);
        row.appendChild(cell5);
        row.appendChild(cell6);
        row.appendChild(cell7);
        row.appendChild(cell8);

        // document.getElementsById("tbody")[0].appendChild(row);

        // var elem = document.getElementsById("tabs1");
        // var mychild = document.getElementById("")
        // elem.insertBefore(mypara, mychild);
        // elem.appendChild(row);
        var element = document.getElementById("tbody");           // afficher le tableau
        element.appendChild(row);                                 // afficher le tableau
    }
```

As you can see, i use a lot of data, but they dont go on my table and they dont show anywhere.
i already check on internet, but didn't find a solution for my problem, a try a lot of thing too, but that don't change anything.
How can i put my data on my table ?

Comment: You're using the wrong syntax for setting `utilisateur`'s properties. Try `:` instead of `=`

Comment: He make me an error on my code if i change it

Comment: what error it will throw

Comment: Is your code in a <script> tag?

Comment: You obviously didn't read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56539121/930393) I gave you the last time you [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56538954/how-adding-a-table-with-js) about this code